# how to analysis String contain multiple list in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string as follows

```py
str = "['A', 'B', 'C'] ['D', 'E', 'F']"
```

I use `json.load` with `ast.literal_eval` neither works

Is there any function that can quickly and perfectly parse this string?

hope through like

```py
parse = str.somethingfunction()
print (parse [0][2])
```

output: `C`

Comment: what is the expected output? is `['A', 'B', 'C'] , ['D', 'E', 'F']`?

Comment: are the arrays separated by , ?

Comment: @VenkataramanR There are no arrays (or lists) here. It's just a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string does not represent a valid Python construct. Therefore, neither eval nor ast.literal_eval will be able to parse it. However, it appears that all you need to do is insert a comma in the appropriate position. You could do it like this:

```
import re
import ast

s = "['A', 'B', 'C'] ['D', 'E', 'F']"

tuple_ = ast.literal_eval(','.join(re.findall('\[.*?\]', s)))

print(tuple_[0][2])
```

**Output:**

```
C
```